# Expectation-Maximization for NLP tasks

Tags: references, expectation-maximization, natural-language

I am looking for resources on Expectation-Maximization for NLP tasks. Ideally, they should be mathematically thorough (vs. just take some soft counts here and there), and give some clear intuitions.

Comment: You can do named entity disambiguation like that in this paper: [Named Entity Disambiguation in Streaming Data](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/mori/research/survey/ACL/P12-1086.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

- *Chapter 14* of the book **Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing** provides a good description of the EM algorithm and its applications in statistical NLP. Here's [Chapter 14](https://wiki.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2010-11/F/6390/_media/chap14.pdf).
- Here's Prof M. Collins [notes on The EM algorithm](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/em.pdf). (Most  comprehensive!)